# Weird drawing when using UICollectionView created programmatically

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating a UICollectionView and its cells programatically. In my custom UICollectionView the only method that is implemented is `layoutSubviews`. Here is the code below for setting up my collection view and handling the delegation. As you can see from the gif once in a while a cell loads correctly, but the majority are misaligned or off screen. I suspect it is something wrong with how they are reused. I usually use tableviews and scrollviews, so I'm not as comfortable with collection views. How can I fix this?

[image]

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 160, height: 200)
    featuredCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame), collectionViewLayout: layout)

featuredCollectionView.delegate = self
    featuredCollectionView.dataSource = self
    featuredCollectionView.register(ItemCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:
    "cell")

// MARK: CollectionView Delegate 

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return 8
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width: 160, height: featuredCollectionView.frame.size.height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return featuredItems.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCollectionViewCell
    cell.item = featuredItems[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

Comment: check the height in your func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width: 160, height: featuredCollectionView.frame.size.height)
} .... sometimes there is a timing problem ... the collectionview could have a unexpected height

Comment: Changing the height didn't work

Comment: @Big_Mac_24 could you post a github project with cells you are using, I would fix it for you

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov Here is a gist with all the code from the cell class https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cd79b8eb5ab8c3153f37d4c7c4410071

Comment: Big_Mac_24, this is extremely incorrect way to `addSubview` in `layoutSubviews`, it is called every time. Why would not you use xib with layoutconstraints?

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov Thats just how I've always done it. I can redo it using a xib, but would that make any difference on the issue I'm having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see your main issue, check the frame of `backgroundCardView`, you're setting it based on the cell's origin within the collection view.

`backgroundCardView.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x + 8, y: self.frame.origin.x + 8, width: self.frame.size.width - 16, height: self.frame.size.height - 16)`

This is going to be way outside the cell's bounds, which is why it appears to be laying out incorrectly. Also, you should add subviews to the cell's `contentView` instead of directly to it's view. As noted in other comments, you shouldn't add views in `layoutSubviews`. A better place would be inside an init method.